# What is the difference between normal method call from native method call?

Tags: android, android-ndk

```
//my class
class NDKSupport {

    // Loding library
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("NDKTest");
    }

    // Stuff in NDKSupport
    public native String getMessageFromNDK(NDKSupport support);

    public String getMessage() {

        // doing some stuff over here
        return "SOME RESULT";
    }
}

//Native code


 JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
 Java_com_afbb_ndkcheck_NDKSupport_getMessageFromNDK(
 JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jobject ndkSupport) {

 jclass ndkSupportClz = env->GetObjectClass(ndkSupport);

 jmethodID getInstallationSource =
 env->GetMethodID(ndkSupportClz,"getMessage", "()Ljava/lang/String;");

 return (jstring)env->CallObjectMethod(mainActivity, getInstallationSource);
 }
```

Now in another class I'm creating Object and calling 2 methods both will do same stuff. what is the difference between those two calls either in performance wise or in another.

```
NDKSupport support = new NDKSupport();

// what is the difference between these two calls

String d = support.getMessage();
String d2 = support.getMessageFromNDK(support);
```

give me some info regarding this or if any tutorials available.
Excuse me for my English ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Native methods are platform-specific code. They are usually written in languages such as C or C++ and contained in libraries(dll's). It is possible to create a hybrid Java application that benefits from such libraries.

**Reasons for Using Native Methods**

1. Gaining access to special capabilities of your device or or Android
   OS
2. Gaining extra speed
3. Gaining access to a large body of existing legacy code

Typically, good use cases for the NDK are CPU-intensive applications such as game engines, signal processing, and physics simulation

The **major disadvantage** of native methods is that you won't have **cross-platform capability**.

Now if you don't know what native code is, then probably you don't need to use native code. Android NDK documentation explains this well:

> ..., you should understand that the NDK will not benefit most apps. As
>   a developer, you need to balance its benefits against its drawbacks.
>   Notably, using native code on Android generally does not result in a
>   noticable performance improvement, but it always increases your app
>   complexity. In general, you should only use the NDK if it is essential
>   to your app—never because you simply prefer to program in C/C++. When
>   examining whether or not you should develop in native code, think
>   about your requirements and see if the Android framework APIs provide
>   the functionality that you need.

Comment: @Canar Thank u for ur response. u mentioned that "The major disadvantage of native methods is that you won't have cross-platform capability.". what is cross-platform here. can u please elaborate it.

Answer (score 1):

The NDK allows you to write code using C/C++ and then link it into your Java application. You can potentially increase the speed of your application.

The downsides to the NDK are, it only compiles to specific CPUs (whereas staying in Java land means it will work on any targetted version of Android).

Native C code would use the underlying operating system's (linux) APIs (system calls), and hence would be much faster than when java code would have to be interpreted through the JVM.Most games use the native C code libraries for 2D / 3d graphics, input, sound etc...

SO there is no difference but you can increase your code performance and if you want to code for some specific cpu you can go with native methods but if you want to make an app that is compatible with all type of cpu's you can use simple java methods.
you can use any method according to your application requirement.
you can follow some video tutorials [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YvCRlJToCAg). it is well explained and nice tutorial.
there are many tutorials here-
[first](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/android/Android_NDK.html)[second](https://trivedihardik.wordpress.com/2011/06/16/hello-world-example-using-ndk-in-android/)[third](https://www.android-ide.com/tutorial_androidndk.html)

Comment: Thank u for ur clear explanation. as u mentioned that "for some specific cpu you can go with native methods". "specific cpu" means..? can u please explain a bit more.

Comment: There are various types of cpus families. Currently only following families are supported- •ANDROID_CPU_FAMILY_ARM
•ANDROID_CPU_FAMILY_X86
•ANDROID_CPU_FAMILY_MIPS etc. you can serach andorid documentation fro this.